# Which of the following functions is even?

Tags: calculus, even-and-odd-functions

Let $f(x)$  be a continuous function. Which of the following must be an even function?

$(1) \int_{0}^{x} f(t^2)\mathop{dt}$

(2) $\int_{0}^{x} f(t)^2\mathop{dt}$

(3) $\int_0^x t(f(t) - f(-t))\mathop{dt}$

(4) $\int_0^x t(f(t) + f(-t)) \mathop{dt}$.

I know an even function satisfies $f(x) = f(-x)$, so I thought it should be the first one since $t^2 = (-t)^2$, but the integral is confusing me. I know for sure that $f(x^2)$ would be an even function without the integral, but the integral makes me think that this is a trick answer. I'm thinking it might also be 4, because I saw somewhere that the integral of an odd function is an even function, and $f(t) = t(f(t) + f(-t))$ satisfies $f(-t) = -t(f(-t) + f(t)) = -\left(t(f(t) + f(-t))\right) = -f(t)$ (it's odd).

Can someone please explain which of the two reasons are right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $F(x)=\int_0^x t(f(t)+f(-t))\,dt$.  Then,

$$\begin{align}
F(-x)&=\int_0^{-x}t(f(t)+f(-t))\,dt\\\\
&\overbrace{=}^{t\mapsto -t}\int_0^x (-t)(f(-t)+f(t))\,(-1)\,dt\\\\
&=\int_0^x t(f(t)+f(-t))\,dt\\\\
&=F(x)
\end{align}$$

Hence $F(x)=F(-x)$ and $F(x)$ is even.

Can you do the other three?

Comment: So option $1$ fails because $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t^2) \mathop{dt}$ so $F(-t) = \int_0^{-x} f(t^2) \mathop{dt}$ and substituting $t = -t$ gives $\int_0^{x} f((-t)^2)(-1) = \int_0^x  -f(t^2) \mathop{dt}$, which isn't equal to $F(x)$?

Comment: @hom $$\int_0^x  [-f(t^2)]dt = -\int_0^x f(t^2)dt.$$

Comment: I see. So option $1$ satisfies $F(x) = -F(x)$, which means that it's actually an odd function (and thus, wrong). Thanks!

Comment: Yes.  Option 1 is an odd function.  And you're welcome.  My pleasure.